# Insert value at page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using this plugin: https://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

How can I insert the slider value in the blue circle `at the page loads` ?

What I tried:

```
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $('.slider-handle').text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
 var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
    slider.on("slide", function(sliderValue) {
    $('#example-6 div.slider-handle').text(sliderValue);
 });
}
```

How you initiate slider?